# How can I resolve a circular import of two Python classes in the same module?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I have two tightly-coupled Python classes that need references to each other (at the class, not instance, level). How can I resolve the circular imports? Ideally I'd like to be able to make it work either within the same module or between two distinct modules, but I'll settle for one or the other.

```
# yin_yang.py

class MyYin(Yin):
    __yang__ = MyYang

class MyYang(Yang):
    __yin__ = MyYin
```

Comment: `resolve the circular imports` - what are you trying to prevent? What kind of problems is this causing you?

Comment: @wwii - I get various compilation/pylint errors for various techniques I've tried. (Not including the ideas below.)

Comment: `various compilation/pylint errors ` - is kind of vague. Without knowing what exactly what you are trying to correct how can we help. Especially if none of the current answers are satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

You could set the class attributes for one or both classes after they have been declared.

```py
class MyYin(Yin):
    pass

class MyYang(Yang):
    __yin__ = MyYin

MyYin.__yang__ = MyYang
```

Answer (score 2):

While @phillip-martin's response is the most pythonic one, there is an alternative way to accomplish the task:

```
from werkzeug import LocalProxy


class MyYin:
    __yang__ = LocalProxy(lambda: MyYang)
    foo = 42


class MyYang:
    __yin__ = LocalProxy(lambda: MyYin)
    bar = 9002


print(MyYin.__yang__.bar)
print(MyYang.__yin__.foo)
```

And the magic behind `LocalProxy` trick comes from overriding all the `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, `__etc__` methods. Check it out in the [werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/f7374b6bbadefc073def6a2fed85c33784ff1abc/src/werkzeug/local.py#L253-L420) repo.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants references to the class not an instance.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. But this doesn't change the approach, just remove parentheses in lambdas.

Comment: Cool solution. Depending on the development philosophy of the individual, I could see this being a better way to go. It certainly has the advantage of making the class completely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

When the Python interpreter finds a class declaration, it creates a new scope and executes the code inside the class in this code block, i.e., all class variables are instantiated when the class declaration is executed.

You can avoid this in a really simple manner:

```
class MyYin(Yin):
    pass


class MyYang(Yang):
    __yin__ = MyYin

MyYin.__yang__ = MyYang
```

or

```py
class MyYang(Yang):
    pass


class MyYin(Yin):
    __yang__ = MyYang


MyYang.__yin__ = MyYin
```